# How to do 1-of-X or Y-of-X public key based encrypt/ decrypt in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I would like to be able to encrypt data using public keys, and decrypt the encrypted data using private keys.

Encryption essentially needs to accept inputs:

1. Clear data to be encrypted
2. A list of several public keys
3. The minimum number of private keys corresponding to those public keys that are needed to decrypt the encrypted

How can this be done in NodeJs?

---

#### Scenarios

By way of concrete scenarios, where there are 5 users (A - E) with crypto key pairs in the system.

A 1-of-X scenario:

- `encrypted = crypto_encrypt(clearText, [A.publicKey, B.publicKey], 1)` (1-of-2)
- `decrypted = crypto_decrypt(encrypted, [A.privateKey])`

  - *success*: `decrypted === clearText`
  - because `A.publicKey` was used in encryption
- `decrypted = crypto_decrypt(encrypted, [C.privateKey])`

  - *failure*: unable to decrypt
  - because `C.publicKey` was not used in encryption

A Y-of-X scenario:

- `encrypted = crypto_encrypt(clearText, [A.publicKey, B.publicKey, C.publicKey], 2)` (2-of-3)
- `decrypted = crypto_decrypt(encrypted, [A.privateKey, C.privateKey])`

  - *success*: `decrypted === clearText`
  - because both `A.publicKey` and `C.publicKey` was used in encryption
- `decrypted = crypto_decrypt(encrypted, [C.privateKey, E.privateKey])`

  - *failure*: unable to decrypt
  - because while `C.publicKey` was used in encryption, `E.publicKey` was not

---

#### Ideally...

- At minimum I need to be able to support the 1-of-X scenario, but if Y-of-X is also possible, that would be better
- What the actual key pairs are is not so important here, could be RSA, could be any of the elliptic curves. If the method supports a number of different ones, and allows one to pick, that would be better
- Preferably not tied to the use of any particular toolset or framework

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic.  Look at Shamirs Secret Sharing Algorithm.  Not inherently asymmetric but you could make it so.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Yup I have skimmed several papers, and it looks like this should be possible using many different types of schemes. However, there appears to be a gap between theoretically possible and concretely possible, which I am trying to fill.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark speaking to your comment that "Library recommendations are off-topic", I'll amend the question to ask "how to do this" instead of "what libraries can be used to do this" -  hopefully this falls within the purview of S/O. Otherwise LMK how else I should rephrase this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGP can do this.

Specifically for node, `openpgpjs` has a section in the README - https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs#encrypt-and-decrypt-string-data-with-pgp-keys - which could be condensed into:

```
    const encryptedText = await openpgp.encrypt({ message: clearText, publicKeys });
    const decryptedText = await openpgp.decrypt({ message: encryptedText, privateKeys });
```

However:

- for number of keys required to decrypt, it only supports the 1 of many scenario, not the more general some of many scenario you'd ideally want
- supports both RSA and many elliptic curve based keys, but the key format is designed for use by PGP, as the name of the library implies (so it is specific to the PGP toolchain)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Luke Joshua Park in the comments, this sounds like a textbook use case for a [secret sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing).  Specifically, I would recommend that you:

1. Generate a random AES (or other symmetric cipher) key.  Make sure to use a cryptographically secure RNG (such as [Crypto.randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)) for this, since an attacker who can guess this key can also break the entire scheme!
2. Encrypt the data with this key, using an authenticated encryption mode such as [AES-SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297) (as provided e.g. by [miscreant](https://github.com/miscreant/miscreant)).
3. Split the AES key into multiple shares using [Shamir's secret sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) with the desired reconstruction threshold.  (Some JS implementations I found with a quick Google search include [secrets.js](https://github.com/grempe/secrets.js), [jsss](https://github.com/alevy/jsss) and [ThresholdJS](https://github.com/karlgluck/ThresholdJS).)
4. Encrypt each share using a different user's public key.
5. Send each user their encrypted share and a copy of the AES-encrypted data.

> **Disclaimer:** I have not reviewed the security or correctness of any of the APIs or libraries linked above.  The cryptographic techniques they claim to use appear to be sound and suitable for this task, but I cannot guarantee that they have been implemented safely and correctly.  *Caveat emptor.*

To decrypt the data, each user can first decrypt their share of the AES key using their private key, and a sufficient number of the decrypted shares can then be combined (using the same implementation of Shamir's secret sharing as used to create them) to reconstruct the original AES key, which can then be used to decrypt (and verify the integrity of) the data.

Note that Shamir's secret sharing implicitly assumes that the users who combine their shares to reconstruct the secret will trust each other and not lie about their shares or otherwise misbehave.  If that's not necessarily true, there are various ways for a malicious user to trick the others — perhaps most simply by waiting for everyone else to reveal their share to them and then refusing to reveal their own share to the others.  In general, preventing such attacks is all but impossible without the help of some kind of a mutually trusted party.

At the very least, though, using an encryption mode like AES-SIV with built-in authentication *should* ensure that users will detect if the reconstructed AES key is incorrect, since the decryption will then fail.  If you want to be extra sure of this, you *may* wish to also send each of the users a secure cryptographic hash (e.g. [SHA-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)) of the AES key, so that they can verify its correctness before attempting decryption.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer Ilmari! Unfortunately SSS does not look like it will work for my use case - for non-cryptographic reasons - because I cannot do this: `5. Send each user their encrypted share and a copy of the AES-encrypted data.` The architecture does not support a means for the server to "push" shares to each client, rather the clients need to be able to retrieve the encrypted data, and be able to decrypt it using their own private key(s) - hence I've asked for a means to do this using public key encryption (and not secret key encryption).

Comment: @bguiz: Does your server know the public keys of the clients in advance? If yes, you can just generate and encrypt the shares for each client, and store them on the server until the client connects and requests them. If not, you could still pre-generate the shares but store them unencrypted on the server until the client requests them; of course, this means that you'd be storing unencrypted shares on the server, which could be an issue if the server might get compromised.

Comment: It's also technically possible to dynamically create new shares on demand with SSS, but not all implementations may support it. Also, it requires storing the SSS polynomial coefficients, which include the secret itself (so, again, compromising the server could then compromise the data). And, of course, if the server doesn't have some way to reliably identify the clients (like, say, a public key for each of them), then you'd have to worry about the possibility of a malicious or compromised client tricking the server into giving it multiple shares.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestions Ilmari, but  neither storing unencrypted shares on the server, nor sending private keys to the server are feasible options here. That's why I think a public key based encryption system is necessary here. Something similar to the PGP option presented in the other answer, but also supporting Y-of-X encryption would be great.

Comment: @bguiz: I think there's some kind of a misunderstanding here. In the scheme I proposed above, there's no need for the server to know the clients' *private* keys. All it needs is the *public* keys, so that it can encrypt the shares.

Comment: Yep I misunderstood your 2nd last comment. Upon a re-read I think this might be feasible in may use case:
(1) server obtains the public keys for 2 or more users (2) server encrypts data using AES-SIV (3) server uses SSS to split AES encryption key, with Y-of-X threshold specified, and encrypts each split part using public key (whose threshold is 1-of-1), storing this in encrypted form (4) client retrieves & can only decrypt 1 of the split AES key shares (5) 1 or more clients send may combine their decrypted split AES key shares to obtain the full AES key -> used to decrypt the encrypted data.

Comment: ^ Also, the above comment sounds like I'm rehashing much of what you've said in your original answer - and it is - just pared down to the parts that are relevant to my use case. Thanks!